# how to locate an element of a page after new data loaded on the same page in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to copy the table data of the html page which is loaded on the same page after clicking on the 'Get Table' button on the previous page. However, as the page url is not changing I am getting exception of 'No such element' when trying to locate new elements on newly loaded page. Following is the code I tried:

```
 package com.test.selenium;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
 import org.junit.runners.Suite;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

 import junit.framework.Test;
 import junit.framework.TestSuite;

 public class Example1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Java Stuff\\Selenium Tutorial\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.oanda.com/currency/table");

    WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.name("date"));
    date.sendKeys("12/04/10");

    WebElement date_frmt = driver.findElement(By.name("date_fmt"));
    date_frmt.sendKeys("yy/mm/dd");

    WebElement curr = driver.findElement(By.name("exch"));
    curr.sendKeys("US Dollar.USD");

    Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Currency")));
    sel.deselectAll();
    List lsize = sel.getOptions();
    int count = lsize.size();

    for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
        String lvalue = sel.getOptions().get(j).getText();
        sel.selectByVisibleText(lvalue);
    }

    WebElement crr = driver.findElement(By.name("dest"));
    crr.click();


    driver.getCurrentUrl();

    String table = driver.findElement(By.id("converter_table")).getText();
    System.out.println(table);


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to exception it seems that element not exists on the page, or smth wrong with you xpath. Why you use xpath?! Try css selectors (they are more powerful and stable) =) e.g.

```
driver.findElement(By.css("#converter_table"));
```

P.S. if you want to verify that your selector is correct (no matter xpath or css) use dev console in browser (e.g. for css enter $("#converter_table") in console, and if element exists (and this id has no type in the name) then you'll see what this selector will return)). For xpath use $x("xpath")

**UPDATE:**
Simple solution i think is to add some method which will wait for element, some period of time. Below sample code in C# (test with wait method)

```
        private IWebDriver driver;
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            // Here i just create browser as you (firefox, chrome etc);
            driver = CreateBrowser("http://www.oanda.com/currency/table");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Dispose();
        }

        [Test]
        public void PortTest()
        {
            var dateElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("date"));
            dateElement.SendKeys("12/04/10");

            var dateFrmt = driver.FindElement(By.Name("date_fmt"));
            dateFrmt.SendKeys("yy/mm/dd");

            var curr = driver.FindElement(By.Name("exch"));
            curr.SendKeys("US Dollar.USD");

            var crr = driver.FindElement(By.Name("dest"));
            crr.Click();
            WaitUntilLoad();
            var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("converter_table"));
            Console.Write("the text is " + table.Text);
        }

        public void WaitUntilLoad()
        {
            int repetitionCount = 0;
            bool isLoaded = false;
            while (!isLoaded)
            {
                var table = driver.FindElements(By.Id("converter_table")).Count;
                if (table > 0 )
                    isLoaded = true;
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                repetitionCount++;
                Console.WriteLine("Searching again for element");
                if (repetitionCount > 25) break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, xpath was wrong. I corrected it with id. However the same exception exists. The main problem here is that the newly loaded page has same url as the previous page, so whenever I try to locate an element it searches on the previous page.

Comment: It doesn't matter for webdriver is this same url or not, it will perform search in current page. I think problem in other place. Could you provide sample of html before and after clicking on 'Get Table' btn? Also, as suggestion, add some sleep time after clicking on your btn, may be page not updates and driver tries to search non-existing element. And provide htmls please. Thanks.

Comment: It's better you try this link yourself http://www.oanda.com/currency/table coz the html code is too lengthy n I'm confused what part will be more useful for u. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Its working fine now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Got it... I also got same exception sometime. The problem as i said before, that browser need some time to update page structure. I've added simple WaitUntilLoad method which will wait until loading element on the page (but this method can be improved much more =)) it's up all to you. Anyway updated test, works on my side very stable.

Comment: @Andrey Egorov, why make it so complicated? use explicit waits instead! I have updated my answer. For more info read the selenium documentation "WebDriver: Advanced Usage" http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: yeah, you are right ) I know about explicit and implicit waits

Answer (score 0):

you get NoSuchElement because your xpath seems wrong

try

`WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content_section']/table")));`

`String table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content_section']/table")).getText();`

Comment: Even if I correct xpath or use other options the same exception persists because the main problem here is that newly loaded page has same url as of previous one, so when I try to locate the element there it still thinks of the last page. I guess the new data is loading on the same page. How should I solve this?

Comment: @Shreyansh, the code is working fine with the changed xpath expression and FirefoxDriver.